# React quantity update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `5` items in a cart and each item has a quantity of `1`.

I have used `Addbuttons` and decrease buttons to increase and decrease the value of each item.

I am using a `setState` with `0` as the initial value but on clicking the add or decrease button for a single item it is increasing the value of all the items.

What should I do to increase or decrease the value of the item I click ?

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

import './index.css'
import books from "./bookinfo.js";

const Book = () => {
  let [state, setState] = useState(books);
  // let value;
  // let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const AddItems = () => {
   
  };
  const DecreaseItems = () => {
    //  value = quantity - 1;

    // setQuantity(value);
    // console.log(value);
   // window.localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(state), JSON.stringify(value));
  };
  const TotalItems=()=>{
    // console.log(value);

  }
  
  const RemoveSingleItem = (id) => {
    let removeBook = state.filter((items) => items.id !== id);
    setState(removeBook);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {state.map((book) => {
        const { id, img, title, author,qty } = book;
        return (
          <div key={id} className="container">
            <img src={img} alt="" />
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <h5>{author}</h5>
            <h5>{qty}</h5>

            <button type="button" className ="btn" onClick={() => AddItems()}>
              Add Item
            </button>
            <button type="button" className ="btn" onClick={DecreaseItems}>
              Decrease Item
            </button>
            <button type="button" className ="btn" onClick={() => RemoveSingleItem(id)}>
              Remove Single Item
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <section style={{ margin: '4rem 0', textAlign:"center"}}>
      <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={() => setState([])}>
        Delete Item
      </button>
     < button type="button" className="btn" onClick={TotalItems}>
        Total Items
      </button>
      </section>
      
    </>
  );
};
export default Book;
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**ES6 Style & Single line code**

Just grab the previous value from the state and update it with `+` or `-` and done.

Try the following code:

```js
  // Quantity State
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

  // Increase Quantity
  const AddItems = () => setQuantity(quantity => quantity + 1);

  // Decrease Quantity
  const DecreaseItems = () => {
    if(quantity > 0) setQuantity(quantity => quantity - 1);
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You should pass qty as parameter in AddItems/RemoveSingleItem in order to increase/decrease quantity and then update `state`.
TIP: Note that updating state will render the complete Book component, you will probably need to improve that in order to rerender only the modified book.